# Youtube Live Video Streams dosen't work in qtwebengine

Tags: qt, qml, qtwebengine

I was trying to make a browser that can support Disney+ and YouTube live streams using QtWebEngine. But it isn't playing youtube live video. Say's "this browser doesn't recognize any of the video formats available" or something like that. This is my qml (made no changes in cpp code).

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtWebEngine 1.0
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    WebEngineView{
        id:view
        objectName: "view"
        anchors.fill:parent
        settings.pluginsEnabled: true
        url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iL53Y28Rp84"

        Text {
            id: element
            x: 16
            y: 18
            width: 52
            height: 25
            text: view.loading ? "loading.....":""
            font.pixelSize: 22
        }
    }
}
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: Why tagged with c++?

Comment: @Thrasher sorry misleading you to my post. I am working with c++ and qt5 for the project. I tagged c++ to indicate I am not using PyQt5 binder. Should i remove the tag